# How to produce in DR scenario with Mirror maker (automatic failover)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying out Mirror Maker 2 on my Kafka 2.4 cluster for DR purposes. I have created a dedicated cluster for the DR. MM2 seems to be working fine, but I not sure how would I be able to produce to a topic in a scenario of a DR.

Current Scenario, let's say I have a topic called **"mytopic"** in my primary cluster and it will be replication to backup cluster with prefix primary called "**primary.mytopic**"

**Primary Cluster1:**

```
  mytopic
```

**Backup Cluster2**

```
  primary.mytopic
```

My app is bootstrapped to the primary cluster to produce to mytopic. In a scenario of DR is there an automatic way to switch the topic to primary.topics with bootstrap to the backup cluster?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
replication.policy.separator=
source.cluster.alias=
target.cluster.alias=
```

in the `mm2.properties` made the topics in the backup cluster not have any prefix.

I am just doing `primary->backup.enabled=true` one way replication.